# Finding the smallest n satisfying $S_n > 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S_n = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \cdots + \frac 1n$, where $n \in \{ 1,2,3,\cdots\}$ Find the smallest $n$ satisfying $S_n > 10$.

Sorry, it's my first time asking and I don't know how to format this thing. I still don't see anything even after staring at this for really long. Any clues?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Formatting advice can be found here:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: you could check this out:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: How are you supposed to tackle this problem? My feeling is that you have to solve it computationally, to realize how slow this grows.

Comment: Try comparing the sum to $\int_1^n\frac{dx}{x}$

Comment: To get it exact is a tedious numerical process, though not difficult.  Start with the standard approximation in terms of logs and the euler constant.

Comment: You can obtain the result by using the Eulero-Mascheroni constant

Comment: Oh wow I thought it was just a math olympiad kind of question. Wasn't expecting to have to use calculus and really complex math but yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an asympotic expansion for $H_n$:
$$H_n = \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{B_{2k}}{2 k n^{2k}} = \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{12 n^2}+ \frac{1}{120 n^4} - \dots$$
Reference : [Wikipedia on Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

So
$$\ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{12 n^2} < H_n < \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}$$
Solving $\ln n + \gamma = 10$ for $n$, we find $n \approx 12367$. With this value of $n$, we compute 
$$ H_n > \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{12 n^2} = 10.000043$$
and $$H_{n-1} < \ln (n-1) + \gamma + \frac{1}{2(n-1)} = 9.999962144$$
so  $H_{n-1} < 10$ and $H_n > 10$ for $n = 12367$.

Answer (score 1):

Should be near

$$ \lfloor{ \frac{e^9}{2} }+1 $$

I use

$$ \int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{t} dt \leq \frac{1}{k} \leq \int_{k-1}^{k} \frac{1}{t} dt $$

You sum and integrate which give you log then you solve for upper and lower bound and verify.

Answer (score 0):

$$12367$$

See my graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/whr6jjuf1e) as a show of that.

By calculator:$$S_{12367}=10.00004301$$

Comment: calculator checking the result now

Answer (score 0):

The $n$-th harmonic number $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$ is asymptotic to $\ln n+\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), equal to $0.57721\dots$

So, if you are searching for an $n$ such that $H_n>1$, you should solve the following equation:

$$
\ln n + \gamma > 10,
$$
and the first integer greater than $e^{10-\gamma}$ is $n=12367$.

This is an estimate of the exact value, one needs some error estimates to find it.

Comment: All this means is that the answer is *near* $12367$. You need some error estimates to nail down the exact answer.

Comment: Ok this is actually pretty new to me, but thanks anyway. So the harmonic series converges to ln n + Euler constant as n increases, so in order to find n for the sum of the series to be more than 10, we let the asymptote be more than 10 then solve for n?

Comment: @shgdhfgxbcv, finding -- and *proving* -- that you have the *exact* value at which $H_n$ first exceeds a given integer is challenging.  See http://oeis.org/A002387 and some of the references there.

Comment: Yes, @BarryCipra is right, my answer is an estimate, then you have to prove (or verify with a calculator) that the answer is correct. I will specify it in my answer.